# How to map Task field type to "Email" created from Lightning for outlook

Tags: email, outlook, lightning-outlook, lightning-for-outlook

We are using Lightning for outlook for logging a email which creates a EmailMessage and Task record in Salesforce instance, Task records created from LFO has type as blank my requirement is to Map type field with "Email" value when task record created from LFO.

How do i achieve this? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "Type" you mean the category or icon shown for the Task in the publisher and activity timeline, such as Email, Call, Meeting, and so forth.

To alter this quality, you must write a `before insert` trigger that sets the Task's `TaskSubtype` field to `"Email"`. This field can only be set in `before insert` context. Your trigger would typically want to check that the running user is that user responsible for Lightning for Outlook syncs before making this change.